# How to avoid noise on serial connection?

Tags: noise, uart, serial

tldr: How can I prevent noise on a short (30cm) serial line?

I'm trying to connect a Jetson Nano to a Sabertooth motor driver via UART (I'm using their "packetized serial" mode, but I don't think that is relevant for my issue). I have used the same driver and code with an Raspberry Pi without issues.

This is working, however, it's not very reliable. About 1 in 10 commands are not received by the motor controller or are interpreted incorrectly.

Things I have already done:

- Disable any other processes, such as a serial console, that may be sending data on the connection
- Add a pull-up resistor (however, according to Nvidia's own documentation this is not necessary and in fact they advise against using it https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads#?search=Jetson%20Nano%20Developer%20Kit%2040-Pin%20Expansion%20Header%20GPIO%20Usage%20Considerations%20Applications%20Note )

I ended up connecting an oscilloscope to the serial transmission pin and I'm seeing a lot of noise:
[image: oscilloscope view of tx data]

The connection is 9600 baud, using a basic jumper cable of about 30cm/12inch. Shorter cables do tend to reduce the noise, but not by a lot.

My question? What can I do about this?

The Sabertooth allows up to 5V on the UART lines, so I could level shift it (nano is 3.3V) but before I go out and buy parts, I want to make sure that this will actually help.

Are there other options? Should I be using a different cable?

---

**Update**: thank you all for the many comments and ideas. I still need to go through Connor's answer. I have a feeling he may be on to something.

This is how I have made the connections. I did connect grounds together, but now I'm wondering if I maybe made a connection to many.

[image: Jetson Nano and motor driver diagram]

(it's maybe not clear from the drawing, but the bottom ground connection on the Sabertooth is the one from the onboard BEC. I'm not using the BEC since it does not provide enough power for the Nano)

I am using a 3s lipo with DC-DC convertor as power source (https://www.dfrobot.com/product-752.html). If the Jetson nano is powered off, but connected this is what the 5V looks like:

[image: 5v nano turned off]

However, as soon as the Nano is turned on, there seems to be an issue:

[image: 5v nano turned on]

I'm not sure what's causing this, but I'm now going to read through Connor's answer and see if I can run some more tests.

Comment: Did you try using a shielded cable which has its shield connected to GND at one side only (source-side, preferably)? In a noisy environment where noise sources such as motors involved it's quite normal to see noise on communication lines.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Do you mean something along those lines? https://be.farnell.com/belden/8761mn-008100/shielded-cable-1-pair-22awg-30/dp/2674698 ? I have not tried this. I'll see if I can obtain this

Comment: I can't give you any specific product code but yeah, one like that should be fine. Remember: You'll need at least 3 conductors: RX, TX and GND. Shield will be separately connected to GND at only one side.

Comment: Is your Jetson Nano powered from a power supply that is as ripple-free as possible? (good, reliable power supply and not Chinese-aliexpress crap). Check your power supply and 5V/3.3V rail for ripple. The noise might be coming from the power supply. Also, if you are not connected to the motor driver, does the same noise appear? Also, I would like to see your hookup. The wires, the connections, some pics would be useful to see where everything is going, how close they are with eachother etc

Comment: If your UART lines actually look like this (and this isn't just a bad measurement) then you have _severe hardware problems_ which need to be fixed by re-designing the hardware. Shielded cables isn't a solution, it's like putting band-aid on a gun shot... You need to post relevant schematics.

Comment: As Lundin says this is not a small problem. Just to make sure because you wrote "using **a** basic jumper **cable**": are you using a single cable from Tx to Rx ? If yes, there is your problem. You MUST co-connect a gnd cable. Otherwise the return current flows through your whole room or not at all, creating arbitrary amounts of noise in the process due to the gigantic loop area.

Comment: Thank you very very much for including an oscilloscope trace! The problem here is not other processes sending data, and it's not a missing pullup...

Comment: you can quickly test the shielded cable idea with some aluminium foil

Comment: @Peter Isn't this what RS-232 was originally designed to cope with, back in the day, with single-ended drivers/receivers?

Comment: @jonk Yes but this is not using RS-232, just direct logic level connection between IO pins.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this kind of issue when you get ground noise between the boards (Jetson and motor drive). Make sure the ground current for the motor does not flow on the ground line between the jetson and the motor controller. See the example below. If that doesn't fix it, your noise is much higher frequency than your signal, so a filter (RC is an easy one to try first) right at the controller receive line may help. In the past I also fixed a similar issue with a ferrite bead on the motor controller positive power wire, which kept the high frequency currents inside the capacitors on the motor drive and away from the system ground.

Here is an example of good and bad ground configurations. Z1 and Z2 are the impedances of your ground wires.

Good:
Power Supply GND <--Z1--> Motor Driver GND <--Z2--> SBC GND

Only the SBC input current flows across Z2. The ground voltage difference between the driver and SBC is Z2*SBC input current.

Bad:
Power Supply GND <--Z1--> SBC GND <--Z2--> Motor Driver GND

The motor drive input current flows across Z2. The ground voltage difference between the driver and SBC is Z2*motor drive input current. Motor drive input current is probably larger and nosier than SBC input current.

Remember that Z2 is an impedance (usually inductive), not just a resistance. More power filtering at the motor driver can help keep high frequency currents off of Z2.

Of course, in large, distributed systems, power filters can get very expensive (and don't solve low frequency issues), and grounding arrangements can't be as simplistic as the one I called "good". That's why these types of systems use differential interfaces like CAN to reject ground noise. When you have a differential interface it is also much easier to use filtering devices like common mode chokes to get rid of common mode noise.

Lastly, when probing for noise in environments with high currents, use the ground spring that came with your scope probe instead of the long ground lead. The ground lead creates a large loop area and can turn magnetic fields into voltages that make it look like there is more noise than there actually is.

EDIT: Looking at the new information you added, the noise may be being injected by the DC-DC that supplies 5v. You should test to figure out where it is coming from. If the dominant frequency of the noise is above 50kHz, and especially if it is around the specified 350kHz switching frequency of the DC-DC, blame the 5V DC-DC. If you have another 5V supply, you could try that (but beware of any grounding changes made in the process that could affect the outcome of the experiment). The module you link to has really poor filtering per its schematic. I would expect substantial ceramic capacitors, or at least polymer capacitors, on the input and output of a converter like this (5A, 350KHz). These really should be on the converter PCB. You could try to tack some on, but if you identify the DC-DC as the problem, I suggest you invest in a higher quality module. The cheap ones like you linked tend to have all sorts of weird issues beyond just noise.